# Can't seem to theme bootstrapped angular-datatable like website example

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, angular-datatables

I have implemented Angular-Datatables into my web application (using Bootstrap styling), and I can't seem to work out how to make my datatable look like the example on their website.

For example their datatable has the following traits:

- Icons against each column header (as highlighted below)
- A white background colour for the column headers
- Striped rows starting with a grey colour, then white, etc.

[image: Datatables Example]

Whereas, my default table has the following:

- An arrow representing the current ordered column (as hightlighted
  below)
- A grey background colour for the column headers
- Striped rows starting with a white colour, then grey, etc.

[image: My example]

I have added the standard bootstrap theme files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../vendor/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.min.css">
```

Setup my default datatable:

```
<div>
     <table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" width="100%"></table>
</div>
```

And have optioned up my datatables with bootstrap:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
            .fromFnPromise(function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve(users); 
                return deferred.promise;
            })
            .withBootstrap() // Style with Bootstrap
...
};
```

Even the examples on the bootstrap website all mimic the datatables format.
Am I overlooking something maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a huge mismatch between different versions laying around on different CDN's. I was really baffled myself, when I ran into the problem.

You are doing it all right, you are just accidently using the "wrong" version `dataTables.bootstrap.js` and its `CSS`. I cannot tell why, I have not seen any explanation at all anywhere, but if you use angular-dataTables, then skip the official bootstrap implementation and download this instead :

```
bower install datatables.net-bs
```

After you have done that, you will discover huge differences in the `dataTables.bootstrap.js` and `dataTables.bootstrap.css` compared to the official [CDN](http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/integration/) versions. The js actually addresses the pagination buttons, the CSS is defining `:after` classes using glyphicon font (what you are looking for) and so on. Again, I cannot explain why there is so different versions.

Here is a demo where I have extracted the above files and used them instead of the official, then it works -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/gOQ4bKOhzzfFgViwuAkb?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for the clarification.  I have downloaded the update and worked through your plnkr.  Adding the new files, it has now themed it much nicer (the glyphs are present, etc.) but I still cannot seem to get the colours right like your demo.  I have adjusted my code to include all the same files as yourself and in the same order, but I still get reversed colours for some reason.

Comment: @Riples, I really dont know, hard to guess - are you setting classes to the table? I had not in the demo, try with `class="table-striped"` only, instead of `class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered"` as in OP. Do you still have any other `angular-dataTables` / vdataTables`  `*.bootstrap.css` included?

Comment: I am marking this as the accepted answer because your advice definitely pointed me in the right direction to address my issues.  In the end it was a mixture of referencing the incorrect CSS files, out-dated JS files (as you suggested) and fine tuning the theme thanks to the help of Carlos13's CSS alternatives.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The standard bootstrap integration looks the same, see [this link](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/bootstrapIntegration).

To override the default classes, do the following:

Grey alternative rows:

```
table.dataTable tbody tr.even {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

Grey heading (added !important to override sorting_asc, sorting_desc styles but you can style these individually if needed)

```
table.dataTable thead th {
    background-color: #EEE !important;
}
```

Sort icon:

You can override the following styles:

```
table.table thead .sorting_desc {
}

table.table thead .sorting_desc:before {
}
```

Comment: could you please identify which classes I would need to override.  I would need to change the column header colour, reverse the rows on `table-striped` and add in the column icons (which I'm not sure how to do).  I thought it would be as simple as bootstrap default for datatables.

Comment: See @davidkonrad's answer above. I'll still leave this answer here though as you'll be able to use it if you want to tweak the styles further.

Answer (score 0):

Download the full `datatables` source code, copy the media folder to your web folder and add the CSS to your code.

The file you will need is `media/css/jquery.dataTables.css`